# JavaFX table view with slider

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I need to make table view for large table. There are about 20 columns and it is the problem for me because I do not know how to make some kind of a slider to make possible looking at any column I want. 
Now I am not able to see all column because my screen is to small. I would like to have "resaizable" tableview.

Comment: If you mean a scrollbar with 'slider', then you should pack your table in a `ScrollPane`.

Comment: `TableView` automatically adds a `ScrollBar` to the bottom of the `TableView`, if the columns do not fit to the `TableView` completely...

Comment: @fabian in my case there is no ScrollBar, I do not why, maybe I should set width for each column or something like that?

Comment: @tomo_s In that case the combined column width does not exceed the space available for the columns. Probably you use some layout that does not resize the child containing the `TableView` or some of the `TableView`'s ancestors has `managed` set to false.

Comment: @tomo_s If there is no scroll bar, then something in your code is causing that to happen. No-one can possibly know what that is as no-one else can see your code.

Comment: I will try one more time do this in scene builder.

Comment: @tomo_s Why don't you post your code?

Comment: Sorry that I forgot to post my code , but last few days I was staying out of home. So i would like to thank you all, you were ritgh. After I did new scene in SceneBuilder everything is ok, table is working well now.